# How to run PowerShell script that in Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Actually i am trying to run a powershell script that will connect to my azure subscription at first with 2 parameters Subscription ID and Tenanat ID then it will generate a information about the Virtual Machine that reside into my subscription and all its releted information. After-that all the information will store in a csv file.

So, i tried to create azure devops pipeline and execute that script using azure devops but it throwing error. in my local system powershell it is working fine. here is pipeline image that i have tried:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrIHf.png)

Error log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnfWX.png)

My goal is to The VM.ps1(Name of my script) script  execution via azure devops it should run as we ask and we pass the 2 parameter tenant id and subscription id to connect first and the output report
should get saved into a common location which can be accessed by everyone.

Can anyone please help how i will do run my script in azure devos from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps, project settings first you need to setup service connection.
for setting up service connection you require, subscriptionid, tenant id, client id and client secret. After setting up service connection, you need to take Azure powershell task in pipeline and paste your code in inline script and click on **save and queue** to run the pipeline.

[image]